# How do I convert int of zeros to int [] (array of digts)?

Tags: java

This did not work when I tried it.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 000000;

        String temp = Integer.toString(num);
        int[] numbers = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            numbers[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }
}
```

it only outputs one zero.

Comment: "*`int num = 000000;`*" - That's the same as `int num = 0;`. Therefore `Integer.toString(num);` will evaluate to `"0"`.

Comment: Start with a `String`. Or just `int[] numbers = new int[6];` (note that `0` is the default value in an `int[]`).

Comment: As in arithmetic, there is only one zero value, no matter how many times you write the character '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Arrays class to convert a string of `decimal digits` to an `int array` of those digits.

```
String digitString = "000000";
int[] digits = new int[digitString.length()];
Arrays.setAll(digits, i-> digitString.charAt(i)-'0');
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

prints

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

There are simpler ways if the digits are all the same.  But the above will work for a string of any decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 000000;
```

This is the same as

```
int num = 0;
```

Instead start with a string and then continue

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String temp = "000000";

        int[] numbers = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            numbers[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }
}
```

Or if you just want zeroes inside the array you could also just do this

```
int[] numbers = new int[6]
```

You could even do this and add any number you like

```
int[] numbers = new int[5]//will make an array of size 5 with all elements 0
Arrays.fill(numbers, 1);//will set all elements to 1
```

Comment: Worth adding that while an integer value specified as 000000 is the same as just 0 in Java, an integer value specified as 010 is not the same as 10, because an integer specified with a leading  0 is an octal integer.

Comment: @Ma3x *Unless* the second character is `x` or `b`, in which case it's hex or binary respectively.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I agree those should be mention in the answer as well.